# add div content on click in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, firebase, angularjs-controller

I am making an async call on click of a button and wanted to add  tags.
I also used s.$apply() - I am new to JS/Angular JS. Could I get help/pointers to similar functionality? I found few examples on show/hide but not any for updating dom.
Thanks

Controller code:

```
    angular.module('solr').controller('SolrController', ['$scope', 'Solr', '$http',
        function ($scope, Solr, $http) {
            var s = $scope;
            s.dataPresent=false;

            s.policies = function(){
                    Solr.getDocuments(s.searchStr).then(function(data){
                         $scope.dataPresent=true;
                         $scope.test="done";
                        console.log(data);
                        $scope.data= data;
                    })
                }
                }
    ]);
```

The HTML snippet is pasted below

```
        <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
    <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
            <li class="sidebar-search">
                <div class="input-group custom-search-form" ng-controller="SolrController">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="searchStr" placeholder="Search...">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="policies()">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                </div>
                <!-- /input-group -->
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10" ng-show="dataPresent">Test</div>
```

Based on this [wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-$scope.$apply()) tried $apply

```
    s.policies = function(){
            Solr.getDocuments(s.searchStr).then(function(data){
                $scope.$apply(function(){
                    $scope.dataPresent=true;
                    $scope.test="done";
                    console.log(data);
                    $scope.data= data;

                })
            })
        }
```

Comment: Failing to see the relationship to Firebase here. Not even a line of Firebase code in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `ng-controller` directive initialize controller with new scope that is
>   available in the context of that element where directive has been placed.

You `ng-show` directive doesn't know anything about `dataPresent` variable, because its not there inside `ng-controller` div, You should ensure that `<div class="col-sm-10" ng-show="dataPresent">Test</div>` div should be inside `SolrController` div.

**Markup**

```
<section data-ng-controller="SolrController">
    ...other html here..
    <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
        <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
                <li class="sidebar-search">
                    <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="searchStr" placeholder="Search...">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="policies()">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                        </button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /input-group -->
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-10" ng-show="dataPresent">Test</div>
</section>
```

Comment: The 'divs' are wrapped by '<section data-ng-controller="SolrController">' and tried '<div ng-controller="SolrController" class="col-sm-10" ng-show="dataPresent">Test</div>' still did not work. Have updated my question with the $apply approach I tried

Comment: @patb23 you took me wrong..you `ng-show` div would be `<div class="col-sm-10" ng-show="dataPresent">Test</div>` without `ng-controller`

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and explanation. I retained ng-controler at 'Section' level and it worked.

Comment: @patb23 Glad to help you..Thanks :)